# How common are orphaned blocks on Ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, forks, uncle-blocks

How often do orphaned blocks happen on Ethereum? I have read about the 3000 orphaned chain of block on Ethereum Classic, what has been the longest orphaned chain on Ethereum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just over 11% of all PoW blocks that were mined result in an orphan. After the merge, it is still possible to get orphaned blocks, but they are more rare.